# Why does Docker run --rm option not work if port is already bound?

Tags: docker

```
$ docker rm containername
containername
```

Then I tried to run a container and assigned it a name `containername`

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 --name containername b014d35f03a
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 2dc7aa98e8213625352e0ef8aadeaa1b6b4a0ab92c6c64c4dafe870b5bb7a49e: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

Why is Docker now saying that `containername` is taken? Shouldn't it have removed the container when it exits since I put in `--rm`? And is there a way to fix this problem? (Always remove container when any exiting)

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 --name containername b014d35f03a
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "containername" is already in use by container 2dc7aa98e821. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error, regarding the port being in use by another application, means that Docker *failed* to start the container:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
2dc7aa98e8213625352e0ef8aadeaa1b6b4a0ab92c6c64c4dafe870b5bb7a49e:
Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

Because it didn't start the container, the client never had the chance to start monitoring it in order to remove it on exit.  I suspect the thinking behind this behavior is that you may want a chance to diagnose this sort of failure, rather than simply deleting the container outright.

You can:

- Open an issue and/or submit code to change the behavior such that the container will be removed in any case, or
- You can use an explicit `docker rm` rather than relying on the client to do it for you.  For example, you could always explicitly `docker rm containername` before starting the container.  This is a fairly common pattern, since it means that in the event of an error the container is still hanging around so you can diagnose it.